# Finite resolution (discrete step) mechanical potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

Are there mechanical potentiometers with discrete lockable stepping instead of the usual gradually variable adjustment? I need a potentiometer that would have a guarantee to stay in selected discrete position. What is the right name for such type of device? (And no, I am not looking for digipots, I need a mechanical device).

Comment: Sounds like a rotary switch with a bunch of resistors.

Comment: How many positions / what resolution do you need? 12 way rotary switches are commonplace and cheap. 24 way can be had, but a more expensive. You could use a coarse and a fine switch if you need high resolution.

Comment: detent potentiometer

Comment: I second 'detent'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are stepped attenuators (often used for audio) which are just rotary switches with fixed resistors, and there are pots with detents.

From [here](https://www.edn.com/audio-step-attenuator-with-47-positions-offers-precise-volume-control/) Eg:

[image]

Or these from [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/414/TTRB_S_A0009241240_1-2565587.pdf):

[image]

These are just the usual mechanical potentiometers with 11, 21 or 41 distinct positions enforced by something like a ball bearing rolling into individual grooves in a circular plate. The positions are not going to be particularly accurate but the pot should not move much from vibration etc.

Of course if you can perform the function electronically, with a digipot or with some signal processing, etc.  then a rotary encoder and an MCU is a possible solution.